# Is there a bag I can use to safely carry my passport and ID whilst travelling?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, security, gear, privacy

First of all sorry for these stupid questions, but normally my boyfriend took care of all these stuff, now I am traveling alone for the first time.

When I go to the airport, they will put my bag under than machine to check that there is nothing dangerous inside.

My question is that I can't put my passport in that bag, maybe something happened, I need to keep the passport in my hand, but I am also afraid to keep on my hand, maybe someone take it.

I thought that there should be a specific bag to hold it in my hand, and I can put my passport and my mobile and my ID and my bank card inside it, what is it please?

(I don't need that bag that every girl have, I need if there is a specific one for the passport)

#### update

after your suggestions, i bought this one, it is so thin so i can hide it under my cloths
[image]

Comment: @GayotFow i am not going shopping, i don't (and i think no one) use passport on shopping, i am asking about airport.

Comment: OK, in that case check out the Victorinox Boarding Pouch; The Victorinox Boarding Pouch tucks inside clothes to secure valuables. It features two large pockets that store most sizes of currency, tickets, passports, traveler's checks and other travel necessities. It also has a micro-screen mesh slot that keeps your ID easily visible and accessible. The secure Victorinox Boarding Pouch with RFID Protection protects you from identity theft.

Comment: No need to apologise for the questions. ;)

Comment: Having a specific bag for the passport is just adding more chances of losing it.. a bag you are not used to carry will have more chances of being lost..

Comment: Heidel has hit the nail on the head.  I mention this in my answer below.

Comment: I use a similar bag like yours and it is worth to mention that airport securities might do a body search on you and ask you to put _this_ bag into X-Ray as well.

In addition, a passport might _not_ be a good item to be put in and hide under your cloth.
It is because you might need to access your passport more frequently than you expected - proof of identity (some destinations require you to have the passport with you all the time), buying discounted train tickets for visitors, buying mobile SIM as vistors, enjoy tax refund for visitors...

Comment: (cont.) This bag is useful when you need to *hide* valuables that _you are not going to use on that day_ (e.g. big load of extra cash).
You do not want to open this bag in public, that would just telling everyone you are carrying valuable items.
Unloading this bag outside just increases your chance of losing it.
Any items that you are going to use between checking-out your hotel in the morning and checking-in at night might not work well with this bag.

You still need to find which part of your regular bag / backpack is less vulnerable to pickpockets for frequently used items.

Comment: The most important is not put something not allowable like knife with your passport, second is dont make it lost

Comment: The safest place is in a pocket with a zipper. Simple, and you don't have to pay too much attention to it.

Comment: You can hold your passport in your hand as you go through security, if you don't want to take the risk of losing it.

Comment: You may have to show it several times. So don't put it somewhere complicated, and certainly not in one of those bags under your clothes. Pickpockets love airports and if one sees you using one of these, they will soon have it off you, especially if you are not used to it. If you printed your boarding pass, put that inside your passport while you walk around.

Comment: I always always always hold onto my passport when travelling through an airport. With all the security that goes on, I find it incredibly rude when anyone asks me to remove it from my person. I hand carry through the metal scanner and have been asked to place it in a tray on a few occasions. Decline gracefully. If that doesn't work, decline firmly.

Comment: What exactly do you imagine happening to your bag in the 10 seconds it takes to pass through a sealed metal box? I can understand travel anxiety but I feel like you went to extraordinary lengths to avoid mentioning either a purse or a wallet in your question.

Comment: @Lilienthal i was concern someone could take the purse from my hand.

Comment: @sarah You might be _even more vulnerable_ when you remove the belt-loop from your body, open it up for getting passport. That would just as easy as your purse for pickpockets / robbers. Unloading the bag from under your clothes could be difficult which you are paying lessing attentions to other threats in open for a long time. If your concerns is that someone could take your purse by force, then you should consider something you could "wear" it, e.g. backpack. Remember it is nearly impossible to be full-proof, we could just minimize the risk.

Comment: @sarah I understand, but at some point you're going to have to thrust *something* to carry your documents. I think instead of gimmicks to hide them (and make them more difficult to access), **it might be more useful for you to ask a new question on good practices or tips to stay aware of your possessions and avoid theft** while transiting through an airport. That doesn't seem to have been asked here before and I'm sure the community has a few useful guidelines they can share on this.

Answer (score 13):

There are wallet-like holders specifically designed to keep your passport and some other cards (credit card, healthcare card etc)

They look like this and can be bought in just about any airport shop I've been to anywhere in the world. 
[image]

This thing is though you can't keep anything on you, everything you're carrying on the plane has to go in those plastic trays through the X-Ray machine. The X-Ray won't damage your passport and no one would try to take your passport, there are so many security people there it would be silly to even try.

That said if you are still concerned you can hand it to the security person and they'll give it back right after you go through the metal detector, this way you know for sure nothing will happen to it.

No need to worry though, everyone does this all the time, in all the security lines I've been in, never seen anyone have problems with that.

Comment: okay thank you i will try to buy it before i travel. second think please, i buy the ticket online, they send me confirmation email, when i go to the airport, should i show them the email? or what?

Comment: On most airlines, 24 hours before the flight they will send you a link to print your **Boarding Pass**. That is what you should bring to the airport. There are, for many airlines, machines at the airport that will take your ID and print them, if you have not had the chance to do so at home. To give a more exact answer, it would help if you post your itinerary, including which airline.

Comment: A lot of airlines now support the electronic pass on the phone too, so you don't need to print it. Just check to make sure it's supported

Comment: I never let my passport leave my person, not even for the X-Ray machine. I hold onto it, visibly, in my hand as I pass through the scanners, even the millimeter-wave ones that they use in the U.S. I've never had an issue with holding onto it, all they do at the other side of the scanner is shake my passport to see if anything falls out of it that I might have been hiding.

Comment: My experience in Japan is they simply won't let you not carry it through.

Comment: @MarkHenderson in some countries the passport is taken out of your hand and placed in the xray machine.

Comment: @JoErNanO I will admit to not experiencing that. I used Singapore and US as my benchmarks for what you can/can't do at security.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus now they sent me an email containing the details of the ticket, (sounds like the payment took 4 hours to be done), they said there is a bar code i have to pass in the airport, the barcode is on the document they sent

Comment: There is a whole variety: (a) you must take it out and put it on a tray (b) you can leave it in your handbag/whatever but put that on the tray (c) you must not put it on a tray, you must take it in your hand as you walk through the scanner and show it to the scanner-person.

Comment: @JoErNanO I've been asked to do this before and have told them politely to Foxtrot Oscar. The passport should never leave your person. Do they ask for your socks? Nope. Why should you let them put your most important travel document in a machine where it leaves your sight and is then publicly accessible on the other side when you may still be in the queue? Insanity if you ask me.

Comment: Is `G055386` you passport number? Not sure what kind of risk there is, but I wouldn't give my passport number in an open forum ...

Comment: @JoErNanO At least in that case you have some level of assurance that the security official is monitoring your passport.

Answer (score 4):

For international trips, I use an wallet that hangs *inside* my trousers on a belt-loop. The fabric is extra-reinforced. [This](http://www.rei.com/product/848120/rei-rfid-hidden-travel-wallet) isn't my brand, but it's the same idea. My wife prefers the money pouch (similar to [this](http://www.rei.com/product/819686/eagle-creek-undercover-deluxe-money-belt)). Travelling together I usually give her my passport too, and we watch *very carefully* for the tray containing the passports to come through the scanner.

Comment: In the tray I usually hide the passport and phone under my jacket or bag, the X-ray operator still sees it I recognize my bag on the other end but no one else notices my passport

Comment: i did what you said, please check my update

Comment: I have the Eagle Creek pouch you linked to. I can highly recommend it. It's survived the Trans-Siberian and multiple trips since - I still use it!

Comment: so you are seriously considering the possibility that someone tries to steal your passport at the airport security check? beside the fact that I don't understand why anyone would do that (but I don't understand everything people do), it is virtually impossible that they wouldn't get caught instantly.

Comment: My wife had a credit card stolen at the security checkpoint once, that had edged out of a wallet or purse. We weren't even sure it was stolen, as opposed to lost, until it was used months later on the other side of the USA. (Bank detected use as fraud.)

Comment: Things are stolen at security checkpoints constantly and always, every second as we speak.  It is, by far, the most likely place you will ever have - anything - stolen in your life. As you say, I don't know if anyone would particularly want to steal a passport, but it would be perfectly commonplace that (say) a baggie or whatever holding a passport would be stolen (even if the thief didn't particularly want a passport.)

Comment: @JoeBlow All the more reason to not put the passport into a baggie. I always simple out my passport openly in the tray and never had any problem with it. As you can see the tray the whole time (except in the X-ray it self, but hard to steal there for outsiders...) I find it very unlikely that someone would snatch it.

Comment: hi Dirkk, yes TBC I totally agree with you. Don't put passport in to baggie.

Answer (score 4):

Hey Sarah here **is one possible solution**,

Keep your passport IN YOUR HAND when you go through the security check. Note that, anyway, in some/many locations **they make you do this**.

Your bag goes through, and **you** walk through the scanner **with** your pport/boarding pass, which you show to the scanning-person.

Regarding generally where to keep your passport:

KEEP IT WITH YOUR WALLET.

It's that simple.

Wherever you keep your wallet (I keep mine .... "in my pocket"), then keep your passport in the same place, with it or perhaps even just inside the wallet.

That's one very simple solution that keeps it clear in your head.

You don't often lose your wallet  ... right?  Your passport is no more or no less important, they're equally important and critical.  So, keep one with the other!

It will always be clear in your mind!

In some cases you MUST put your wallet, and passport, and phone, in a plastic tray and have them scanned.  If that's the case ........ you must do that.

At airports where that is the case, the "BERG" underwear thing will not help you at all in any way, unfortunately.  (Indeed, it will conveniently direct thieves to the fact you are wearing one. :) )

Answer (score 2):

You should try to relax, traveling is a fun experience and although it may seem very complicated once you understand the process its is very simple to get used to it.

**You will need to put *any kind of bag* into the machine. No matter what it contains.** So if you put your passport into this thin bag, you'll have to take it off to put it through the machine.

If you are carrying a laptop, ipad or tablet with you, you'll need to take it out and place it separately.

Always, always, always carry your passport with you on your person. You can walk through the x-ray machine with the passport in your hand without a problem and no one will stop you for carrying the passport. Similarly, make sure you carry your ticket/boarding pass with you as well at all times.

The idea of a passport wallet like what was posted by @blackbird57 is an excellent idea. Another variant (and the one I personally carry) is [this item](https://www.sfbags.com/collections/wallets/products/finn-wallet):

[image]

Since it allows me to carry a few other things and also fits my mobile phone into one item.