# Flying with Iberia, can I carry both a piece of hand-luggage and a backpack?

Tags: air-travel, spain, security, privacy, iberia

okay yesterday i asked a question about how to carry my passport.

i got so many suggestions, that i went and bought one bag but after i showed it to you, you told me it is still not secure.

so i went to the option that i should put my passport in my back bag.

i have to ask is it possible to have a back bag and the starnadrd bag (55*40*25) ?

[this is my airline](http://www.iberia.com/web/product.do?cntCat=Productos/EQUIMA&cntId=EQUIMA&language=en&country=US&market=US&isPopup=true)

second question please
i want to go from home to the airport,

then i have to go to madrid, then from the airport to the hotel to do the check in

then i will be checking places in madrid.

my questoin is: is it save to take my passport in my back bag from my home to the airport, and then after arriving to madrid from the airport to the hotel? then after do the check it, i can hide my passport under my cloth using the bag that i bought it yesterday and that you can see it is picture here: [Is there a bag I can use to safely carry my passport and ID whilst travelling?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59592/which-is-the-bag-to-put-my-passport-and-my-id)

please help i am kind of afraid

#### Update1

[this is my back bag that i bought before](https://www.anypromo.com/getasample.aspx?productid=732455&utm_source=PLA&utm_medium=PC&utm_campaign=732455&g=1&gclid=Cj0KEQiA-ZSzBRDp3ITHm5KO_JYBEiQA1JjHHAENbWVegV7Sz3l-fpLjPSCg-ZK0CdBQJGRXCzevtHoaAhPT8P8HAQ) (of course different colors ) and think i am asking if i can carry it with the standard (55*40*25) bag, i am thnking if they don't allow me to have two, i can put this back bag INSIDE my standad bag because it is almost empty just with some cloth

Answer (score 3):

#### Hand-Luggage Restrictions

The amount of hand-luggage you can carry on-board depends on your ticket fare, and is likely to be written on your confirmation email, or even on your e-ticket. [If your allowance is the one you linked](http://www.iberia.com/web/product.do?cntCat=Productos/EQUIMA&cntId=EQUIMA&language=en&country=US&market=US&isPopup=true), then quoting from the website:

> What else can I take on board besides the permitted baggage items?
>
> - A handbag or small briefcase.
> - A laptop computer or camera.
> - A baby bag with food, drink and materials for the flight.

This means that you can have your 56cm x 45cm x 25cm piece of hand luggage, and a *small* other bag. **The key here is in the size.** If you try to cary both a suitcase and a backpack you will likely be asked to check-in the suitcase. My advice is therefore to use the smallest backpack you can find, and claim that it is a laptop bag, and no more. To be honest I think that a lady's hand-bag will also do the trick. The idea here is that you want the bag to be small enough so as not to be considered as another piece of hand-luggage.

#### Carrying Your Passport

Arguably the question on how to safely carry your passport whilst travelling should be asked on its own. The reason is that there are a ton of tips and tricks one could come up with, and it could make for an excellent Travel question. Having said this, I personally always carry my passport on me when travelling. I never put it in a bag, simply because I think that pickpocketing from a bag is somewhat easier than pickpocketing from a trouser front pocket.

If you decide to carry the passport in your bag, make sure you never leave your bag unattended, and always keep it with you at all times (man I sound just like those security announcements at Heathrow :D).

Having said this I wouldn't worry too much about these things. I understand this might be your first solo-travel experince. However keep in mind that travelling alone is perfectly normal, and that with a bit of caution and awareness you'll have amazing problem-free time.

Comment: thanks for your answer, according to your answer, here is my trick, i will take the standard bag (55*40*25) plus my back bag, if in the airport they said i can't have two of them, then i will put my back bag inside my 55*40*25 bag, **do you think this works?** then when i arrive to madrid, i keep my passport in my secruit bag (the one i showed u in my the previous question) under my cloths, it will be touch my body so i can feel always that it is there, what do you think please? thank you so much

Comment: no i traveled a lot before, but i was always with someone, now the first time to travel a lone thats why i am asking and trying

Comment: i update the question to show u my back bag

Comment: @sarah Having just done the backpack-in-hand-luggage thing with easyjet I would say that **yes it will work**. :) Don't forget also that you can carry as many things you want in your pockets, and coat/jacket pockets. This is a useful trick if you need to empty your hand-luggage to fit the backpack: put socks, and t-shirts in your coat. P.S. [Don't hesitate to come to chat if you need more tips and tricks.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here)

Comment: i hate easy jet, i used it twice, not good at all. now i am with Iberia, so you think it is normal to tell the police in the airport :please stop i will put my backbag inside the standard bag,

Comment: @sarah The airport security staff won't care. It's Iberia who will check luggage size and weight. Airport security mostly cares about dangerous items and liquids.